# Python len() function reporting 'float' error when handling a list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists that I initiate as follows:

```
patches = [[]]
```

and then I append to main list by `patches.append(list_of_x)`, and to the sub lists I append objects by `patches[i].append(x)`.

When I call `len(patches)` I get error "'float' object is not callable".

I did verify by `type(patches)` that Python still considers this a list.

The objects within the sub-lists `patches[i]` themselves have variety of different attributes, but I think that should be irrelevant (right?).

Any idea what kind of witchcraft could be happening?

Comment: My guess is that you're using `len` as a variable name somewhere, thereby shadowing the built-in function.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces your error. As you're stating it now in your question, this error can't happen.

Comment: Yes Tim, I have indeed been this dumb...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have defined a variable called `len` before that in your code. And this variable is probably a float, which, as the error says, you can't call.

Answer (score 0):

don't do patches = [[]]

do it patches = []
when you add, write
patches.append([x,y,x])

like this
patches.append([])

see

```
v = []
v.append([2,2,5,8,2])
v.append([6,6,8,8,7])
print(len(v))
```

2